# What is the elbow point in this plot and how to compute it?

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I would like to find automatically a reasonable elbow point in this plot. In particular to select the value of epsilon in DBSCAN.
The points are sorted on descending value of ordinate.

Visually I would say that the elbow point is when the ordinate is between 0.2 and 0.3, but it is hard to say with precision given the number of points.

How to meaningfully compute the elbow point?

**edit**: by elbow I mean the point `x` in the abscissa where the corresponding value of `k-th nearest neighbor distance` in the ordinate drops with small difference. That is to say that the major drops of the ordinate value were before `x`, and from `x+1` onward there are little drops.

[image]

**edit:** at the moment I compute the difference of ordinate values for consecutive points, and then choose visually between the top N=20 diffs.

Comment: By *elbow* you mean the first meaningful statistical divergence from x = 0? Or, some $\epsilon$ where $x' - x > \epsilon$. If you have the data this seems fairly straightforward. You just need to establish what $\epsilon$ is.

Comment: Relevant info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve

Comment: please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. This is a heuristic, not a truth.

I'd try 0.2 first, then 0.1 (usually, smaller values are better).

But you may even want to check clusters found at the second 'elbow' at around 0.03. Then experiment with increasing/decreasing epsilon if you get too many small clusters, too much noise, or a single too large cluster.

Or use OPTICS.